# how to add different object form my nsarray to nsstring

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsarray

I am having a mutable array which has differnt value at differert index such as at 
index      value
0            Hi
1            this 
2            is 
3            iphone 
4            testing.

So at differnt index ,array has different string value now i want this into one string  which has reads as Hi this is iphone testing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append strings together with
`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", string1,string2,string3];`

Answer (score 8):

You can use this:

```
NSArray *yourArray;
NSString *createdString = [yourArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Separating array components with a space.

Here's documentation for [`NSArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html). Here's documentation for message [`componentsJoinedByString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html).